# Jquery Custom Scrollbar issue

Tags: jquery

I have found this code using Jquery to scroll but I think it was made to scroll the entire body. I want to scroll one part of the page. The container ID is boxL and I can see the divs as well as drag them but the container is not scrolling. Can anyone help me figure out what i need to do?

**EDIT**
I made some change and now it is scrolling but the bar is not following the mouse and the track is not adjusting to the new bottom position; I have also moved the js code at the end of all my code to make sure that everything was loaded.

The scroll bar only move when I reach the bottom of the container.

[Code found here](http://www.designlunatic.com/2012/11/custom-scrollbars-with-jquery/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#boxL').append('<div id="scrollbar-track"><div id="scrollbar"></div></div>');
    function scrollBar(){
        var viewportHeight = $('#boxL').height();
        var docuHeight = $('#boxL').height();
        var trackHeight = $('#scrollbar-track').height();
        var scrollbarHeight = (viewportHeight/docuHeight)*trackHeight;
        $('#scrollbar').height(scrollbarHeight);
        $('#scrollbar').draggable({
            axis: 'y',
            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function() {
                var scrollbarTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
                var scrollTopNew = (scrollbarTop/(trackHeight))*docuHeight;
                $('#boxL').scrollTop(scrollTopNew);
            }
        });
        $("body").bind("mousewheel", function (event, delta) {
            var scrollTop = $('#boxL').scrollTop();
            var scrollTopNew = scrollTop - (delta * 40);
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollTopNew);
            var scrollbarTop = ($('#boxL').scrollTop()/docuHeight)*trackHeight;
            $('#scrollbar').css({
                top: scrollbarTop
            });
        });

    }
    scrollBar();
    $('#boxL').resize(function(){
        scrollBar();
    });
});
```

Comment: *Not scrolling* like what? Can you replicate the issue on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Its not working like it should in the fiddle but i got it to scroll. The scroll bar is not following the mouse and the track is not adapting to the new bottom position